# Two-way bound variable in directive set inside callback not updating outside variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I've ready similar posts here on SO but none seem to quite cut it. I'm taking a shot at creating a google maps directive, which in turn relies on a service I jotted down based on a few readings. Basically my code is on the lines of:

```
var GoogleMapsDirective = function(GoogleMaps) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            map: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var apiKey = "something";
            scope.$watch("map", function(map) {
                //Does indeed log twice: "undefined" and, when the callback is
                //called, the map object returned by the "new google.maps.Map(...)"
                //invokation 
                console.log(map);
            });
            GoogleMaps.init(apiKey, element[0]).then(function(map) {
                scope.map = map;
                //Not good: complains that "$digest already in progress"
                //scope.$apply();
            });
            scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
                GoogleMaps.dispose();
            });
        }
    };
};
var myController = function($scope) {
   $scope.$watch("map", function(map) {
        //this, however, only logs "undefined" the first time
        console.info(map);
    });
};
```

Where `myController` is the controller of a view which basically contains `<div map="map"></div>`.

I'm all out of ideas on how to make my outside `$scope.map` variable get updated when the inner one does (and it does).

Comment: have you tried ... `if(map){ $scope.map = map;}`? Personally I would add an additional method in service ... `GoogleMaps.getMap()` and have it return a promise that gets resolved in `GoogleMaps.init`

Comment: Upon further investigation, I discovered it *does* work, but embedding the `map` directive inside an `ion-content` one does not allow the inner `scope.map` variable to be propagated upwards to the controller `$scope`. Probably because the `ion-content` directive creates an isolated scope. I'll see if I can work around this issue. Cheers.